# DBEdit aparentemente não vinculado ao TADOQuery

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe4, sql-server-2012

Tenho um `ADOConnection`, um `ADODataSet`, `DataSource`, `ADOQuery`, um `DBGrid` e um `DBEdit`.
O `DBEdit` está com a propriedade `DataField = numero`.

Um botão com o teste:

```
AdoQuery1.close;
AdoQuery1.SQL.Clear;
AdoQuery1.SQL.Add('select * from tabela WHERE numero=2 ');
AdoQuery1.Open;
Caption := AdoQuery1.fieldbyname('notaTeste').asString;
```

O comando SQL funcionou corretamente, pois o caption mostra o valor esperado.

Mas, parece que o `DBGrid` e o `DBEdit` não estão vinculados ao `ADOQuery`, porque após dado o comando SQL nada muda no DBGrid e no DBEdit.

**O que estou fazendo de errado?**

Uso [delphi-xe4](/questions/tagged/delphi-xe4) professional e banco de dados [sql-server-2012](/questions/tagged/sql-server-2012).

Comment: Sua pergunta ficou um pouco confusa. Logo no começo do texto você já diz que as alterações feitas no `DBGrid` são refletidas no `DBEdit`, depois fala que não, e depois fala que funciona se for com o `TADODataSet`. Provavelmente sua primeira afirmação de que funciona é com o `TADODataSet`, certo? Não me lembro bem o funcionamento desses componentes já que a muito tempo trabalho só com o componente `Query`. Mas aparentemente o `TADODataSet` já gerencia tudo, porém não é muito recomendado. Já o componente `Query` não gerencia outros tipos de requisição dessa forma.

Comment: Bom, vou esclarecer.

Comment: O dbgrid e o dbedit estão vinculados corretamente com a tabela.

O comando SQL no adoquery funciona. Coloquei o resultado no caption para mostrar o teste, que esta funcionando.

Porém, ao efetuar este comando select no tadoquery, eu esperava que apenas os registros pertencentes a seleção aparecessem no dbgrid, como acontece se eu coloco o mesmo comando na propriedade commandtext do tadodataset.

Isto é, o query é executado, mas o dbgrid e o dbedit não são atualizados.

Comment: Então você precisa editar sua pergunta para melhorá-la. Porque não dá para entender isso. E deixa eu corrigir um equivoco cometido. Disse que o `TADODataSet` não é recomendado, mas me confundi de componente e o que disse foi sem fundamento.

Comment: Você muito provavelmente está comentendo algum erro que está trazendo mais registros então. Experimente tirar o `TADODataSet` do seu projeto de teste e verifique as ligações com o `DataSource`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nos datasets, a propriedade DataSource é apenas para fazer mestre/detalhe.
A linkagem para exibição e edição é: **Dataset -> Datasource.Dataset -> DBControle(s).Datasource**

Mestre/Detalhe: **DatasetMestre -> DataSource.DatasetSet -> DatasetDetalhe.DataSource**

Exemplo(Edição/Exibição):

```
var  
  DtsVenda : TAdoQuery;  
.  
.  
DtsVenda.Close;  
// Sql só para simplificar. Sempre usar consultas parametrizadas   
DtsVenda.SQL.Text := 'select * from Venda where DatePart(month, DHVenda) = 3';
DtsVenda.Open;
DSVenda.Dataset := DtsVenda;
DbGVenda.DataSource = DSVenda;
DBEVenda.DataSource = DSVenda;
```

Exemplo(Exibição com Mestre/Detalhe):

```
var  
  DtsVenda,
  DtsItemVenda : TAdoQuery;  
  DSMVenda : TDataSource;
.  
.  
DtsVenda.Close;  
// Sql só para simplificar. Sempre usar consultas parametrizadas   
DtsVenda.SQL.Text := 'select * from dbo.Venda where DatePart(month, DHVenda) = 3';
DtsVenda.Open;
DSVenda.Dataset := DtsVenda;//Até aqui tudo ok
DbGVenda.DataSource = DSVenda;
DBEVenda.DataSource = DSVenda;

DSMVenda.Dataset :=  DtsVenda; // Só para o mestre detalhe
DtsItemVenda.Close;
DtsItemVenda.SQL.Text := 'select * from dbo.ItemVenda where Id_Venda = :Id_Venda'
DtsItemVenda.Open;
DtsItemVenda.DataSource := DSMVenda;
```

Comment: Resolvido. No TADOQuery deixar a propriedade DataSource em branco. No TDataSource, propriedade TDataSet digitar ADOQuery1 (ele não oferece automaticamente, por isso demorei para perceber)